# How should I use html5 elements with modal sections of my web page?

Tags: html

I'm pretty inexperienced as far as html goes and even less so with html5.

I have a question regarding modal popups - page sections that are interacted with using javascript/ajax, but not necessarily displayed on the page all the time. These are not generally in the main html flow - I might for instance place all my modal code at the end of the page for maintainability. The question is - should I be declaring these chunks of the page using html section tags, or something else?

To shed more light on the situation I'm describing, I have an application page. This contains a number of sections (I'm not referring to html5 here). The first section is modal on entering the page - it's a "click to continue if you agree" section. The next 5 chunks belong to a stepped application form - each step is displayed on at a time using a multiview control. Then another modal - a UI block, followed by a final decision section.

Comment: It's not clear from your question what you are asking help with. Do you mean declare a `<section>` tag? Do you have any code samples that you would like to reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The question is - should I be declaring these chunks of the page as sections, or something else

One of the big advantages of HTML5 is it's sematically readable. If you feel that your modal pop ups are better described by something like an `article` tag, then use an `article`. Use the tag you feel most accurately describes your functionality.

For example, let's say I have a sample page like so:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
      <article>
         <!-- Some stuff here -->
      </article>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would *expect* the content of that `article` tag to fit this definition:

> The article element represents a component of a page that consists of a self-contained composition in a document, page, application, or site and that is intended to be independently distributable or reusable, e.g. in syndication. This could be a forum post, a magazine or newspaper article, a blog entry, a user-submitted comment, an interactive widget or gadget, or any other independent item of content.

*[W3C Specification. The Article Element.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-article-element)*

**Note**: In this context, an `article` is designed to represent flow content. Given that your aim is not to write flow content (as you correctly put) this is not a good example. This is very clear from the definition I've provided.

Similarly, if I replaced `article` with `section`, I would expect it to fit this definition:

> Examples of sections would be chapters, the various tabbed pages in a tabbed dialog box, or the numbered sections of a thesis. A Web site's home page could be split into sections for an introduction, news items, and contact information.

*[W3C Specification. The Section Element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-section-element)*

If I were you I would have a look through the spec and think the following questions:

- What does my content actually mean to the user?
- How will my content appear to other programmers?
- Does the use of this content give me a hint at the correct semantics?

Comment: `<article>` seems inappropriate for modals…

Comment: I was more trying to convey the thought process that he should go through to help get to the answer on his own in the future. I'll make that point clear, but I don't believe in just handing the answer to people.

Comment: To shed more light on the situation I'm describing, I have an application page. This contains a number of sections (I;m not referring to html5 here). The first section is modal on entering the page - it's a "click to continue if you agree" section. The next 5 chunks belong to a stepped application form - each step is displayed on at a time using a multiview control. Then another modal - a UI block, followed by a decision section.

Answer (score 2):

Since they are modal, and appear out of the flow, it is probably most suitable to use a div for them. If you do want to use a semantic block, then which you use will depend on what the content is, and how it relates to the rest of the page. The following articles should help you make that decision:

- http://html5doctor.com/the-section-element/
- http://html5doctor.com/the-article-element/
- http://html5doctor.com/avoiding-common-html5-mistakes/ (particularly the first section of that article - "Don’t use section as a wrapper for styling")

Edit: Have added that 3rd link, since I now have enough rep to do so :-) yay!

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you have in your modal.

You could have a login form, subscribe stuff, advertisements, articles, a frame of another page, so it would only make sense to use `<section>` if they are actually an interesting section of the page, for example, you have an article and then you want to display the *autor info* in a modal box, then I would say that it would acceptable to use `<section>`.

So overall if it is part of the *content* then sounds ok to use that, if is is not you should use a `<div>`.

I would also say that no one has the answer for this as it is purely opinionated, and quite frankly doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

There is also another way to incorporate modals. As they are dependent of JavaScript you could also load the popup contents via AJAX without having them in the document flow. A recent project I worked on, first renders links to a normal and complete HTML page for popup contents (e.g. contact forms). If JS is enabled, a parameter is added to the links to load only the main content without header, menu and sidebars via AJAX.

As the modal content does not really belong to your site content (if it does it shouldn't be a popup but within the documents main content) it shouldn't get marked up with some `section`, `main` or `article` tag. Instead use a `div` to render the popups or use an `iframe` if that is admissible for your project.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really matter what tag is used for a modal, as long as it's appropriate the purpose (don't use a `<fieldset>` for example). Usually we see a `<div>` representing a modal.

You can use the [`role`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-role/) attribute for semantic information about the purpose of an element. In this case `role="dialog"` would be appropriate. You can find more info on the `role` attribute in HTML5 [here](http://www.w3.org/wiki/PF/XTech/HTML5/RoleAttribute).

Also note [ARIA](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/) attributes: They enhance accessibility. For example `aria-hidden="true"` specifies that the element isn't visible. Screen-readers use this to skip the content.